# Place an object on the right side of another object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm an Unity beginner and struggling to place an object right next to another object. The one object is a copy of the other one. I was thinking I could take the x position of the (left) object and get the width of the gameObject/sprite, divide it by 2 and I should have it... But instead both objects are overlapping instead of being placed right next to each other. Where is my mistake? I'd appreciate any help.

```
vector = new Vector3(transform.position.x + renderer.bounds.size.x/2, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Comment: what is not working? I mean what exactly do you expect / what happens instead?

Comment: Both objects are overlapping instead of being right next to each other.

Comment: are both of the same size? You have to move the second object by half of the size of **both** objects

Comment: Yes, both objects are the same size. They rely on the same btimap/sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both objects have the same size rather use

```
vector = transform.position + Vector3.right * renderer.bounds.size.x;
```

the offset has to be the **complete width** of the objects not only half of it.

---

If they had different widths it would be

```
vector = transformA.position + Vector3.right * (rendererA.bounds.extends.x + rendererB.bounds.extends.x);
```

where `extends` equals `size / 2f`.

Comment: are you sure the sprite has no transparent border e.g. ?

Comment: You're spot on. Deleting the dividing by 2 in my code solved the issue and because the objects have a transparent background and I'm still struggling navigating through the scene window I didn't even realize that this fixed it. Thank you both for your help.